# Linking to scripts or images will change page rank?

Tags: web, seo, search-engine

If i create some useful services like some dynamic free photos or some useful java scripts, for example http://www.mysite.com/ipaddress.jpg

and then other websites use this image or script in their webpages... dose it count for link popularity for me (inbound link) and does it increase my website ranks from google point of view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Emiswelt said, no one knows Google's secret algorithms, ask a SEO.

However, most conventional crawlers only follow anchor tag hrefs.

If you search for filetype:.jpg on Google, you will not get any image results and only actual pages are shown. Images and javascripts cannot have any outbound links, and thus pagerank is probably not applicable to them.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, the actual system is top secret, but all the major search vendors support things that help describe images better, in particular [RDF (Resource Description Framework)](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-rdf-syntax/).  It is probablly your best bet at providing information about your images in the most useful way that will hopefully give them an appropriate page rank.

Answer (score 1):

The PageRank value reflects the importance of certain web pages an not that of a whole web site.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody knows this exactly, google's algorithms are a big secret...

Answer (score 0):

It probably does not boots your page rank (I sincerely hope not!), but there is no way to know for sure.  Besides, if it boost it today, there's no guarantee it will still boosts it tomorrow.

If you are think of doing clever things just to boot your site's ranking, I'd think again.  If you are too blatant about it and Google catches you, your site might get zero ranked.  And as a user of Google, I think that is a good thing.